# How To Determine How Many Effective Pixels Is Half The Screen?

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-10, pixel, win-universal-app

I'm having some troubles understanding the concept of effective pixel if there isn't some kind of maximum bound we can sum to (like Bootstrap/Semantic UI columns).

Let's say I always want to have my app do something when the window is at half the width of the display resolution, and let's I have two devices, one is 1920x1080 and the other is 2160x1440 (Surface Pro 3 resolution). Effective pixels tells me I can design something for one device and it should scale accordingly for the other device. Given this information, and any other kind of device resolution, what number of effective pixels do I use to always trigger the said half-screen resolution event?

Microsoft tells me the "breakpoint width" for desktops is 1024 effective pixels, but if I set the event to occur at 512 effective pixels, I do not get my goal behavior. Reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn958435.aspx

**TL;DR** : 
More specifically, I'm trying to make an adaptive trigger fire when the window is half the length of the screen resolution, but I don't know what amount of effective pixels to use, or if I can use percentages instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this; you don't know how big the screen is (in any unit of measure) so you can't know how big half the screen is.

Some caveats:

- If your app is full-screen, obviously you do know the size, but in general you don't
- In the latest insider build of Windows 10 you can get the size of the screen and do some math

The question I'd have though is why do you want the trigger to be half the screen? That is a huge range of sizes from a few inches / few hundred effective pixels for a small tablet to over a foot / a few thousand pixels for a big screen.

Comment: Okay, for my case using screen resolution isn't a viable solution, I agree. But let's say I have two buttons side-by-side which control the content below it (a pivot if you will). These buttons together take up the entire screen width.  
Now let's say I want to do a translation animation from one button to the next when the other one is selected. How is that possible if I don't know the width of the buttons and they are instead in a grid? I couldn't use effective pixels to have each button take up half of the window could I? Then translate-x by that value?

Comment: To split buttons 50/50, use Grid with two columns, each with "*" sizing. You can then get the `ActualWidth` property of the `Button` to get the size.

Comment: But that's not possible with an animation, right? Because using a binding with an animation doesn't work since it's not thread-safe.

Comment: It appears to work if I use a DataTemplate that has a Grid within a Viewbox. The grid holds the two buttons and has a specified number of effective pixels for its width. Then in the root grid I plop that DataTemplate in the first row, tell it to stretch horizontal alignment and Auto on the row height. Somehow it takes up the whole width of the screen and I can translate X on the buttons based on the grid width I used.